# Precedence of Function Overloading Parameters in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following contrived example:

```swift
protocol Fooable { }

extension Int: Fooable { }
extension Double: Fooable { }
extension Bool: Fooable { }

func go(value: Any, type: Fooable.Type) -> String {
    return "Fooable"
}

func go(value: Any, type: Int.Type) -> String {
    return "Int"
}

func go(value: Any, type: Double.Type) -> String {
    return "Double"
}

let value1 = 1
go(value: value1, type: type(of: value1)) // Returns "Int"

let value2 = 2.0
go(value: value2, type: type(of: value2)) // Returns "Double"

let value3 = true
go(value: value3, type: type(of: value3)) // Returns "Fooable"
```

This is the behavior I ultimately want, but what sets this precedence? The more generic, first function can be placed anywhere in the code, giving the same results, so there must be some sort of precedence rules.

Is this outlined anywhere?

Comment: What is your question? Swift infers the type and method signature and calls corresponding method.

Comment: Why have the second argument on any of these functions? Can you just have `func go(value: Fooable)`, `func go(value: Int)`, `func go(value: Double)`?

Comment: The exact issue is a bit more complicated to explain. I'm working with the `Encodable` / `Decodable` protocols, but what I'm wrapping has some pretty ambiguous types and can actually morph values based on the underlying storage type and resulting variable. The above is basically how `JSONEncoder` works with these constraints: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L2084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword here is "specific". Swift always finds the most specific overload to call.

Swift first infers that `value1` is of type `Int`, so `type(of: value1)` is of type `Int.Type`.

Now we've got a `Int.Type` as the parameter, Swift looks for an overload that accepts one parameter whose type is exactly `Int.Type`. It finds one and calls that. The one that accepts a `Fooable.Type` is not called because it can already call a more specific one that accepts exactly a `Int.Type`. Here, "specific" means lower down the type hierarchy. `Int` is considered more specific than `Fooable` because `Int` conforms to `Fooable`.

`value3` is inferred to be of type `Bool.Type`. There is not overload that accepts a `Bool.Type`, so Swift has to look up the type hierarchy and finds the one that accepts a `Fooable.Type`. This is the most specific type that you can pass a `Bool.Type` into.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to just go for the most concrete type first and then fall down from there. I just wasn't sure if there was something more formal.

Comment: For instance, I added a `Barable` protocol and applied it to just `Bool`, then created a `go` function for `Barable`, and at that point, the compiler considers it too ambiguous.